# Utilisation des prépositions « à » et « en » avec un véhicule

Tags: prépositions, transports

Si je ne me trompe pas, on utilise « *à* » lorsqu'on est *sur* un véhicule et « *en* » lorsqu'on est *dans* un véhicule.

Exemples :

- Je vais **à** vélo, **à** cheval, **à** pied…
- Je vais **en** voiture, **en** train, **en** avion…

Pourquoi dit-on : « Je vais **en** skate-board », et non pas : « Je vais **à** skate-board », alors qu'on est *sur* le skate-board et pas *dedans* ? Y a-t-il une règle ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Je me suis posé une question similaire en entendant un journaliste se moquer d'une politicienne parce qu'elle encourageait les gens à rouler *en vélo*, alors que pour lui il fallait dire *à vélo*.

J'ai donc voulu vérifier [l'entrée correspondante du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bicyclette), ce qui devrait être un réflexe dans de tels cas, pour apprendre que dans le cas précis du vélo ou de la bicyclette, les deux sont valables et ont leurs défenseurs et adversaires.

Manifestement les grammariens puristes préfèrent *à vélo*, suivant le raisonnement que le cycliste n'est pas à l'intérieur de son vélo, et que *en* ne devrait servir qu'à remplacer *dans*. Comme indiqué par le TLF, ce raisonnement est bancal, au vu d'expressions comme *en scène*, *en mer*, ou *en tête du championnat*.

En ce qui me concerne, je préfère la recommandation qui suit:

> Quand il s'agit de manières de se déplacer, il semble que l'usage tende à opposer les inanimés *(aller en train, en métro, en voiture, en avion, en vélo, en bicyclette)* et les animés ou parties d'animés *(aller à cheval, à pied, à quatre pattes)*.

Comment: Pour [Yves Montand](http://musique.ados.fr/Yves-Montand/A-Bicyclette-t61778.html), « Quand on partait de bon matin, Quand on partait sur les chemins, **À bicyclette** »
.... Même si votre discrimination est plaisante, je préfère l'usage ancien pour l'écrit. Peut-être parce que cette formule reste dans l'oreille (à l'époque c'était indiscutable, on n'était pas *[dans un]/en vélo*). Une licence poétique *en bicyclette* auraient énervé les instituteurs héritiers loyaux de la IIIème République, l'usager roulait *à bicyclette* jusqu'à la fin du deuxième millénaire.

Comment: Merci, très intéressant.

Answer (score 6):

Je tente une première explication : on dit probablement aller « en planche à roulettes » (même si *skateboard* est aussi employé en français) par analogie avec « aller en patins » (à roulettes/à glace).
Et on dit *en patins* parce que les patins on les enfile, on est dedans, comme on est dans un véhicule, alors que le cheval et le vélo on les enfourche, on est dessus.

Je ne mettrais pas « aller à pieds » dans cette série, car c'est une expression bien particulière, même s'ils servent de moyen de locomotion les pieds nous les avons sur nous, attachés à notre corps, ils ne sont pas « une pièce rapportée ».

Comment: c'est, effectivement, une explication qui tient la route.

Comment: @M42: « qui tient la route ». C'est le cas de le dire! :)

Comment: Et si je longe le littoral en surf ? (voire en tapis volant)

Comment: Je pense que la construction est la même pour toutes les planches, qu'elles soient à voile, à roulettes ou de surf.

Answer (score 4):

« Je vais **en** vélo » est aussi tout à fait français.

Je ne pense pas qu'il existe de règle bien précise sur l'utilisation du « à » ou du « en », mais plutôt que c'est un cas de la langue française ou les coutumes et les habitudes forment la règle.

L'historique pose l'utilisation du « à » (les premiers moyens de locomotions étaient « à pied » et « à cheval », mais je trouve que le « en » s'impose de plus en plus.

Personnellement, pour les « vélo », « bicyclette », « trottinette » et autres deux-roues , j'utilise « à » s'il y a une description qui suit le moyen de locomotion et le « à » ou le « en » indifféremment sinon:

> - Je vais à vélo au marché.
> - J'y vais en vélo -- J'y vais à vélo.

Par contre, il est vrai que je ne dis jamais « Je vais à skate-board »

Comment: Cela ne me semble pas correct de dire `en vélo` bien que ce soit couramment utilisé. Par contre pour trotinette je préfère dire `en trotinette` plutôt qu'`à trotinette`

Comment: @M42. Je [cite](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/v%C3%A9lo) : « Faire du vélo; être, aller, monter, rouler **à/en** vélo, sur un vélo ».

Answer (score 2):

- If the means of transport is **‘closed’** (i.e. your are ‘in it’),
  you use the preposition **en**  after the verb aller.
- If the means of transport is **not closed**(i.e.you are on it rather
  than in it) , you use **à**.

Attention :
For  means of transport with two wheel, **à** is often used instead of "en" in **informal speech**, e.g. :

> en vélo  instead of à vélo.

However, this is considered incorrect!

Comment: I've never heard this kind of distinguishes between transport with 2 or 4 wheels. Do you have some references about that?

Comment: @M42 : I heared that from my french teacher. I think you can find it in the sorbonne books